# In Javascript, can you use one function to store both query strings and persistent cookies?

Tags: javascript, cookies, query-string

I've created a function that stores state information in a query string (first name, last name, cwid, and semester).  If I want to store the first name and last name as persistent cookies and keep the semester as a query string, can I use the same function or must I create two different functions?  Right now I have it as:

```
function saveInfo() {
    var savedData = location.search;
    var studentData = "";
    if (savedData != "")
        studentData = savedData.substring(savedData.search("&courses"), savedData.length);
    savedData = "?firstName" + document.forms[0].firstName.value;
    savedData += "&lastName=" + document.forms[0].lastName.value;
    savedData += "&cwid=" + document.forms[0].cwid.value;
    savedData += "&semester=" + document.forms[0].semester.value;
    savedData += studentData;
    location.href = "greendale_page2.html" + savedData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would create a function which reads the cookie values into your form inputs first. On the other hand you need a third function which saves the values to the cookie. The function you have I would not change if it works for you.

Comment: Yes it works, but part of the assignment is that the first and last names are persistent cookies.  I did the whole assignment in query strings to make sure it was working and then modify it as I go.  Are you saying that I should keep ALL the values as query strings, then make first and last name cookies also.

Comment: From where you get the data when the cookie does not exists?